# Compile PHP with ZTS support on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, build

I've been trying to compile PHP with ZTS support with no luck. I've tried following a few articles but this one seems to fit my requirements perfectly -

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/enable-zts-support-on-ubuntu-14-04

However, I just can't get this working.

If I compile the source with no changes, it compiles fine. As soon as I perform the following steps -

> Find the section starting with
>   COMMON_CONFIG=--build=$(DEB_BUILD_GNU_TYPE) \ and add the following
>   configure flags:
>
> ```
>         --enable-maintainer-zts \
>         --enable-pthreads \
> ```
>
> Then we want to bump the version number for the package, so that it is
>   higher than the version of PHP in the repository. Run dch -i and
>   create a new changelog entry:
>
> php5 (5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.5+zts1) trusty; urgency=medium
>
> - Rebuild with ZTS support.
>
>   -- You   Mon, 10 Nov 2014 13:14:32 -0500

I get the following output (only showing where errors started appearing) -

```
  libtool: compile:  /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/meta_ccld -IZend/ -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/in                                            clude -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/main -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/date/lib -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/lib -I                                            /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/enchant -I/usr/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-g                                            nu -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I                                            /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/                                            libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/pspell -I/usr/include/tidy -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/TSRM -I/                                            php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/main -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/TSRM -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ -D                                            _FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -fs                                            igned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -g -pthread -DZTS -c /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o Zend/.libs/zend.o
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend.c: In function 'zend_error':
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend.c:1043:28: warning: 'error_lineno' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
          active_opline->lineno = error_lineno;
                                ^
    echo "# Generated by Makefile for libtool" > Zend/zend_dtrace.d.lo
    if CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -fsigned-char -fno-stri                                            ct-aliasing -g -pthread -DZTS" dtrace -G -o Zend/.libs/zend_dtrace.d.o -s /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.d  main/.libs/main.o Zend/.libs/zen                                            d_API.o Zend/.libs/zend_execute.o Zend/.libs/zend_exceptions.o Zend/.libs/zend_dtrace.o Zend/.libs/zend.o 2> /dev/null && test -f "Zend/.libs/z                                            end_dtrace.d.o"; then \
              echo "pic_object='.libs/zend_dtrace.d.o'" >> Zend/zend_dtrace.d.lo ;\
            else \
              echo "pic_object='none'" >> Zend/zend_dtrace.d.lo ;\
            fi
    if CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -fsigned-char -fno-stri                                            ct-aliasing -g -pthread -DZTS" dtrace -G -o Zend/zend_dtrace.d.o -s /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_dtrace.d main/main.o Zend/zend_API.o Zend/zend_e                                            xecute.o Zend/zend_exceptions.o Zend/zend_dtrace.o Zend/zend.o 2> /dev/null && test -f "Zend/zend_dtrace.d.o"; then \
              echo "non_pic_object='zend_dtrace.d.o'" >> Zend/zend_dtrace.d.lo ;\
            else \
              echo "non_pic_object='none'" >> Zend/zend_dtrace.d.lo ;\
            fi
    /bin/bash /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/libtool --preserve-dup-deps --mode=compile /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/meta_ccld -Iext/date/lib -Ie                                            xt/date/ -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/include -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/main -I/php5-5.5                                            .9+dfsg -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/date/lib -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/lib -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2                                             -I/usr/include/enchant -I/usr/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.                                            5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/                                            php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/postgr                                            esql -I/usr/include/pspell -I/usr/include/tidy -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/TSRM -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/m                                            ain -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/TSRM -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_REENTRANT  -I/usr/include -g -O2                                             -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2 -Wall -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -g -pthread -DZTS  -c                                             /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c -o ext/date/php_date.lo
    libtool: compile:  /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/meta_ccld -Iext/date/lib -Iext/date/ -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/ -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/php5-5.5.                                            9+dfsg/apache2-build/include -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/main -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/date/lib -I/php5-5.5                                            .9+dfsg/ext/date/lib -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/ereg/regex -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/usr/include/enchant -I/usr/X11 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr                                            /include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/oniguruma -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/                                            ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/ext/mbstring/libmbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apac                                            he2-build/ext/mbstring/libmbfl/mbfl -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/pspell -I/usr/include/tidy -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg                                            /apache2-build/TSRM -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/main -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend -I/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/TSRM -I/php5-5.5.9                                            +dfsg/apache2-build/ -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format                                            -security -O2 -Wall -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing -g -pthread -DZTS -c /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o ext/date/.libs                                            /php_date.o
    In file included from /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/main/php.h:39:0,
                     from /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:21:
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c: In function 'php_date_do_return_parsed_time':
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:2992:71: error: 'TIMELIB_SPECIAL_FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH' undeclared (first use in this function)
        add_assoc_bool(element, parsed_time->relative.first_last_day_of == TIMELIB_SPECIAL_FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH ? "first_day_of_month" : "last_day_of                                            _month", 1);
                                                                           ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_API.h:387:68: note: in definition of macro 'add_assoc_bool'
     #define add_assoc_bool(__arg, __key, __b) add_assoc_bool_ex(__arg, __key, strlen(__key)+1, __b)
                                                                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:2992:71: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
        add_assoc_bool(element, parsed_time->relative.first_last_day_of == TIMELIB_SPECIAL_FIRST_DAY_OF_MONTH ? "first_day_of_month" : "last_day_of                                            _month", 1);
                                                                           ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_API.h:387:68: note: in definition of macro 'add_assoc_bool'
     #define add_assoc_bool(__arg, __key, __b) add_assoc_bool_ex(__arg, __key, strlen(__key)+1, __b)
                                                                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c: In function 'php_date_timezone_set':
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3320:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'timelib_set_timezone_from_offset' [-Wimplicit-function-                                            declaration]
        timelib_set_timezone_from_offset(dateobj->time, tzobj->tzi.utc_offset);
        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3323:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'timelib_set_timezone_from_abbr' [-Wimplicit-function-de                                            claration]
        timelib_set_timezone_from_abbr(dateobj->time, tzobj->tzi.z);
        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c: In function 'timezone_initialize':
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3659:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'timelib_parse_zone' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      dummy_t->z = timelib_parse_zone(&tz, &dst, dummy_t, &not_found, DATE_TIMEZONEDB, php_date_parse_tzfile_wrapper);
      ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c: In function 'zif_timezone_transitions_get':
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3912:20: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
       if (tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt > 0) {
                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3924:34: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
        } while (begin < tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt);
                                      ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3929:20: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
       if (tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt > 0) {
                        ^
    In file included from /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/main/php.h:39:0,
                     from /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:21:
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:37: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                                         ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_API.h:385:92: note: in definition of macro 'add_assoc_long'
     #define add_assoc_long(__arg, __key, __n) add_assoc_long_ex(__arg, __key, strlen(__key)+1, __n)
                                                                                                ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:20: note: in expansion of macro 'add'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3930:4: note: in expansion of macro 'add_last'
        add_last();
        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:37: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                                         ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_API.h:387:92: note: in definition of macro 'add_assoc_bool'
     #define add_assoc_bool(__arg, __key, __b) add_assoc_bool_ex(__arg, __key, strlen(__key)+1, __b)
                                                                                                ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:20: note: in expansion of macro 'add'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3930:4: note: in expansion of macro 'add_last'
        add_last();
        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:37: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                                         ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/Zend/zend_API.h:390:111: note: in definition of macro 'add_assoc_string'
     #define add_assoc_string(__arg, __key, __str, __duplicate) add_assoc_string_ex(__arg, __key, strlen(__key)+1, __str, __duplicate)
                                                                                                                   ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3901:20: note: in expansion of macro 'add'
     #define add_last() add(tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt - 1, timestamp_begin)
                        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3930:4: note: in expansion of macro 'add_last'
        add_last();
        ^
    /php5-5.5.9+dfsg/ext/date/php_date.c:3935:36: error: 'timelib_tzinfo' has no member named 'bit32'
       for (i = begin; i < tzobj->tzi.tz->bit32.timecnt; ++i) {
                                        ^
    make[1]: *** [ext/date/php_date.lo] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/apache2-build'
    make: *** [build-apache2-stamp] Error 2
    dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
    debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
    dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

I've tried this is on a brand new EC2 instance more than once and consistently get the same issue. 

I'm obviously doing something wrong but I have no idea what it is. Does anyone have an idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I got it to work with php 5.4.41 on an RaspberryPi 2 / Raspbian but got the same error when trying on Ubuntu with 5.5.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. For the sake of anyone finding this in a search - I ended up spinning up a CentOS instance instead and the PHP build worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've spent the entire day trying to fix this exact problem, but could not find a working solution anywhere. Changing an OS was a bit too radical for me so I went [this route](https://blog.flowl.info/2015/compile-php-5-6-pthreads-mongo-ubuntu/) instead. It will allow you to use optional php5-zts for certain scripts. I also skipped all steps related to mongo so I can't say whether they work or not. However, there are several important adjustments which should be applied to this guide as of 19.02.2016 or it will not work.
1) Current master branch of pthreads is targeted at php7 so instead of

```
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.git
```

run

```
git clone https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads.git --branch PHP5 --single-branch
```

or your build attempts will fail.

2) First time you run make command it might fail because there's no "makefile" in the source directory. I honestly have no idea which one is supposed to be used so I had to guess it's "Makefile.global":

```
cd /usr/local/src/php-5.6.12
./buildconf --force
make -f Makefile.global clean
```

All subsequent make calls will remember that makefile so you won't have to specify it again.

3) Finally author messed up the ln syntax, the arguments' order should be reversed:

```
ln -s /usr/local/src/php-5.6.12/sapi/cli/php /usr/bin/php5-zts
```

Aside from that it was a great guide which saved my day.

PS: It seems there's some error lurking in Date extension because I keep getting php warnings even after I've successfully built php with this method when I run scripts with pthreads, and that same extension is the one giving a fatal error in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed this problem

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

you need to choose your local timezone and retry all.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't confirm this as I used CentOS instead

Comment: Tried this on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and did not work. Still getting same error