# How to compile & install official PHP-8 with ZTS? (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, ubuntu-20.04, php-8

As title says, how to compile and install official PHP-8 on linux/ubuntu with Zend-Thread-Safe support? I've seen using 3rd party repositories, but wanted the steps for official PHP-8.

Comment: (btw, this is old question, obsolete : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001606/compile-php-with-zts-support-on-ubuntu-14-04 )

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/php/php-src.git
cd php-src
./buildconf
./configure --enable-zts
make -j4
make install
```

Comment: What does the -j4 do?

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289250/using-make-with-j4-or-j8

Comment: -j parameter defines how much CPU cores the compiler should work with. Higher = faster compilation speed.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of using `ondrej` repository (as seen on many sites) I've found a way to install PHP-8 from official php.net packages. I've followed [this tutorial](https://www.rapidspike.com/blog/php72-pthreads/) , however, just changed `php7` references with `php8` and it succeeded.

However, during installation I needed to do:

- apt-get install sqlite3 re2c
- apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
- apt-get install libonig-dev

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it summarised the key steps itself. As it is, if the tutorial you linked to goes offline, the answer won't really say anything.

Comment: You can use `--without-sqlite3 --without-pdo-sqlite` to avoid the need to install sqlite

Comment: Ondrej sury no longer packages php with zts  - you are left to build from source. https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1392#issuecomment-623591749